# doctype html tag is adding vertical cell spacing to table

Tags: css, html

I have a table that has 0 cell spacing and padding and fits together perfect.

When I add:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

A bunch of vertical cell spacing is added throwing the design off.

I added 100% height to the `body` and `html` tag like this post said: [Make div 100% height of browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window)

But this did not help.

Here is my html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%; min-height: 100% !important;">

<head>




</head>

<body style="height:100%; min-height: 100% !important;">

  <table id="Table_01" width="300" height="300" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <img src="images/test_01.png" width="300" height="22" alt="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="139" height="258" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Test</td>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <img src="images/test_03.png" width="12" height="278" alt="">
      </td>
      <td width="149" height="121" bgcolor="#000000">
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="149" height="121" alt="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="149" height="137">
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="149" height="137" alt="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="images/test_06.png" width="139" height="20" alt="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="images/test_07.png" width="149" height="20" alt="">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

**How can I render this table with no spacing or padding?**

Comment: Don't use the `!important` CSS declaration and with `html` and `body` just set `height` and not `min-height`. Also, avoid inline styles - write a `<style></style>` block. Finally, what EXACTLY do you want here? You are setting the `height` of the table to 300, so you are going to get vertical spacing.

Comment: Tables are designed to describe relationships between rows and columns of data, not jigsaw images together. You should be using CSS for your layout.

Comment: but my table is 300 without spacing, why would that add spacing vertically?

Comment: This looks like a Photoshop "save for web" export option. Ran into this too ... JIC it helps ... after you're done doing the slices in the save for web dialog box and hit save; in the next dialog where you choose where to save; change the settings drop-down option to other, then in the slices drop-down of the next dialog box you can choose CSS instead of table. It will save all of your slices to DIVs instead of in tables which makes it a lot easier to deal with formatting. A lot better in the newer Photoshop but should be there as early as CS4.